# Waiting on tasks to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I'm new to threading and i'm trying to figure out a way to use tasks to accomplish this :

```
private void botCore()
{
    if (CheckBox2.Checked == true)
    {
        Task Core =  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Proxy -> Next");
            Webbrowser1.Navigate("www.lalaland.com")

        });
        Core.ExecuteFor(2000)); // Executes the task above for only 2000 milliseconds then proceeds

        if  (Core.IsCompleted)              // Checks if the 2000 milliseconds are up then executes another statement.
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Proxy -> Next after next");
            Webbrowser1.Navigate("www.balalala.com")
            ExecuteFor(3000) //Execute this for 3000 milliseconds.
        }
        Core.Stop();
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to run a task for x amount of time, once the the task completes it runs another task for x amount of time and does it in a loop. If this can be accomplished in a better way, like UI-threaded, please provide me a source to work from. I'm pretty new to C#. Thanks to anyone who supports me.

Comment: `await Task.Delay(2000);`

Comment: I think what newStackExchangeInstance is trying to say is that you should be able to replace `Core.ExecuteFor(2000));` with `await Task.Delay(2000);`.

Comment: It doesn't show anything period. No message box or anything else.

Comment: Also delay isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I see two common mistaken assumptions in your code:

- You are calling UI methods from a thread other than the UI thread. In Windows, there is (usually) only one UI thread, and all UI updates must be done on that thread.
- You are attempting to control a thread "externally", telling it to execute for so long and to stop on command. In the general case, this isn't possible; a thread is completely independent and will not stop until *it* wants to.

If you just want to introduce some delays, threads aren't needed. You can do it with `async`:

```
private async Task botCore()
{
  if (CheckBox2.Checked == true)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Proxy -> Next");
    Webbrowser1.Navigate("www.lalaland.com")

    await Task.Delay(2000);

    MessageBox.Show("Proxy -> Next after next");
    Webbrowser1.Navigate("www.balalala.com");

    await Task.Delay(3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it have unexpected behavior? Throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to call `Core.Wait(_time_to_wait_)` and check the return value. If true then task is completed. False otherwise. If the task times out and you want to 'kill' it, refer to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607.aspx

Note that if you call `Task.Wait` immediately after `Task.Factory.StartNew`, the timer may time out even before the task gets executed, because the task is first placed into a queue of a task scheduler and there might be a noticeable delay between the task initialization and execution. To avoid this(if you want precise time control under heavy load, which is the main scenario where the delay will occur), add an extra signal to the task, and wait for it first:

```
var started = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        started.Set();
        //...
    });
started.Wait();
t.Wait(2000);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `Task.Wait` in this case though - that will block the UI thread for two seconds, which almost certainly isn't desirable.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right. Didn't realize this is an UI thread. In this case a new task can be created to handle the waiting. Or we can break down the routine into multiple asynchronous handlers, which is even more difficult for a C# beginner. @ user2476620 If you wrap the waiting code in another task, check this: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If your asking me, i would say start using methods. That for a start. 
Besides that, take a look at this exampel.. It doesn't explain all but it's ok. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610.aspx

NOTE: You can wait on a task. but it will finish when it is done. It will not automatically close after 2000 ms. you will need to do this manually

Besides that try this example,,.. didn't tested it.

```
private void botCore()
{
    if (CheckBox2.Checked == true)
    {
       Task coreTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => printMessage("1", "www.google.nl"));
       await Task.Delay(2000);
       coreTask.Stop() // AS you asked that it will stop.

        if  (coreTask.IsCompleted) // Checks if the 2000 milliseconds are up then executes another statement.
        {
           Task coreTask2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => printMessage("2", "www.google.nl?p=2"));
           await Task.Delay(3000);
           coreTask2.Stop() // AS you asked that it will stop.
        }
        Core.Stop();
    }
}


public void printMessage(string text, string url){
    MessageBox.Show("Proxy -> " + text);
    Webbrowser1.Navigate(url)
}
```